# Generate screenshot of map

Tags: screenshot, leaflet, wms

How can I generate a image of a div, the div contain a map of leaflet (base layers, overlays)?

[image: Screenshot_Leaflet_Div]

Comment: You can provide a print button to print map area. You can also make use of a leaflet print plugin. https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox's [leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) plugin will allow you to kick out an image file of your map container clientside.Enabling canvas mode is required, as seen in their instructions. A more involved server-side approach would include the use of Mapfish/Geoserver and a [leaflet plugin](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.print), which has a lot more flexibility, but also a lot more configuration.

Comment: I tried with leaflet-image, but he problem is leaflet-image doesn't work with layers wms and legends

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you may need to go with the mapfish route.

Comment: @snkashis can you provide any sample usage of leaflet-image plugin?

Answer (score 0):

What I did on a project was run a nodejs rest api that would launch a chromium instance using puppeteer take a screenshot of a map using long lat and then return the image as a base64. It might be more efficient to generate a map image serverside using leaflet or something else rather than taking a screenshot of a browser.

https://github.com/lastlink/re-store/tree/master/webscraper